# Include Composite Diagrams in EA RTF Generation

Tags: enterprise-architect

Using Sparx Enterprise Architect 10:

I have a package containing a diagram and a number of activity elements. The elements are on the diagram and contain a composite activity diagram with elements from other packages. The structure containing the composite diagrams looks like this:

[image: Structure Containing Composite Diagram]

The structure containing all of the tests that are on *Verify Product1* activity diagram might look like this:

[image: Structure Containing Individual Tests]

Is there a way to include the composite diagrams when generating a RTF report?

Currently, my RTF template is set up to process:

- packages
- package elements
- diagrams
- diagram elements

I'd like it to generate something like:

- 1. Verify System1 (package)
- 1.1. Verify System1 (diagram)
- 1.1.1. Verify Product0 (element)
- 1.1.1. Verify Product1 (element)
- 1.1.1.1 Verify Product1 (diagram)
- 1.1.1.1.1 Verify Product1 Subsystem0 (element)
- 1.1.1.1.1 Verify Product1 Subsystem1 (element)
- 1.1.1.1.1 Verify Product1 Subsystem2 (element)
- 1.1.1. Verify Product2 (element)

(Assuming the three test cases are on Verify Product1 diagram.)

**Note: I understand how to create the RTF templates as I need them: what I don't understand is how to indicate that I want the composite diagrams to be processed.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it (with a small trick). You need to follow the hierarchy as shown in the image below
[image]

The expected hierarchy is

Package

->Diagram

->Element

->->Diagram

->->->Element

Now the trick, when you enable the Diagram under Package->Element, you wouldn't have an option to enable Element again, to work around this, enable the "Element" under (Package->Diagram) cut and paste the place holder (element>.....Element->Diagram)

Have exported my template (RTF) for your reference, you can import it and try to apply on your Verify System package)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9y9jo4xk0yq2zf/SampleRTFTemplate.rtf

Comment: This produces exactly what I am looking for. I have not been able to create the template from scratch yet, but I have been able to import and modify your template to add the additional formatting/notes, etc. I'd like to appear. Thank you!

Comment: Would it be possible to re-upload this Template (3 years later :X)

Comment: @SteveKalemkiewicz

Comment: @NizamMohamed  or you?

Comment: @Andrea, Sorry -- I don't think I have the template anymore.